# Planar edge-transitive Cayley graph

Tags: finite-groups, cayley-graphs

To check one of my results, I need the following special example.

Is there a finite group $G$ and a generating set $S=S^{-1}$ such that the degree of Cayley graph $\Gamma(G,S)$ is at least 3 and also it is planar and edge-transitive?

Thanks so much for your helps

Parcly Taxel, kindly presented an example of a Cayley graph of an abelain group with the above properties. This example solves my problem, but I am curious to know that is there a non-abelain example too?
Again thanks so much dear Parcly Taxel

Comment: The cube is also a Cayley graph on the dihedral group of order $8$ (which is nonabelian).

Comment: @verret Thanks so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the abelian group $Z_2^3$ generated by the non-trivial elements of each $Z_2$ factor. The Cayley graph thus formed is a cube, which has degree 3, is edge-transitive and is planar. This gives a positive answer to the question.

Comment: Thanks for your nice example.